# Can't run process with Symfony2 Process Component with XAMPP on windows

Tags: php, symfony, pdf, xampp, phantomjs

I want to use phantomjs to generate a PDF of the current website. The generated commandline is correct! The PATH variable is correct, because if I copy it into a cmd window, everything works perfect, but php has some sort of problem.

> Rasterize script failed.
>   CommandLine: "phantomjs" "C:/xampp/htdocs/excitingfit/app/../web/bundles/padam87rasterize/js/rasterize.js" "localhost/excitingfit/web/app_dev.php/bundles/padam87rasterize/temp/rasterize-54579a69e9c31.html" "C:/xampp/htdocs/excitingfit/app/../web/bundles/padam87rasterize/temp\rasterize-54579a69e9c31.pdf" "pdf"
>   ExitCode: 1
>   ErrorOutput: Der Befehl ""phantomjs"" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
>   konnte nicht gefunden werden.

Comment: It runs with the process component of symfony2. I guess it is proc_open()

Comment: It's not a duplicate, like I said, the PATH variable is set correct.

Comment: That may be, but php doesn't use the system PATH depending on how it is invoked. I'm not familiar with symphony, but I would think it is the same issue.

Comment: Does it work when you use absolute paths for everything to invoke the process?

Comment: I'm running on windows and I don't know what else I coukld do than defining the PATH variable

Comment: Also doesn't work with absolute path.Rasterize script failed.
CommandLine: "c:\windows\system32\phantomjs.exe" "C:/xampp/htdocs/excitingfit/app/../web\/bundles/padam87rasterize/js/rasterize.js" "http://192.168.178.21/excitingfit/web/app_dev.php/bundles/padam87rasterize/temp/rasterize-545a092066bb8.html" "C:/xampp/htdocs/excitingfit/app/../web/bundles/padam87rasterize/temp\rasterize-545a092066bb8.pdf" "pdf"
ExitCode: 1
ErrorOutput: Der Befehl ""c:\windows\system32\phantomjs.exe"" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.

Comment: But if i copy that exact string from the error and copy it into a cmd window it works!